# Braintree payment rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, braintree

Is anyone familiar with Braintree?? According their documents for rails I have to do this: https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/plan/all/ruby   in order to retrieve plans from api.
Then why is it returning this error: `NameError in PlansController#index...uninitialized constant PlansController::BraintreeRails`

```
class PlansController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @plans = BraintreeRails::Plan.all
  end

  def show
    @plans = BraintreeRails::Plan.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `BraintreeRails` with just `Braintree`, as it says in the documentation you linked to.

The error is basically telling you that Ruby does not know of a constant called `BraintreeRails` within the context of your `PlansController`, as you have mistyped the name.

Comment: No problem. To avoid problems like this in the future, try to verify that you follow the documentation to the letter.